# How to include sonar exclusion for gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, spring-data-jpa, sonarqube

I tried to include sonar exclusion but is working on a single class I have 5 classes to exclude all are in different packages of gradle project.

Build. gradle

```
sonarqube{
       properties{
          property"sonar.sourceEncoding","Utf-8"
          property "sonar.ProjectName","ixxxx"
          property "sonar.projectKey","org.sonarqube:ixxxx",
          property "sonar.exclusions","**/*pxxxx.java"
                }
         }
```

please help with suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Just separate your individual classes by comma.

```
property "sonar.exclusions","**/*pxxxx.java, **/*Axxxx.java, **/*Bxxxx.java"
```

Comment: thanks, it's not working throwing an error in the sonar. could not  find method property()

Comment: do you have `apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"` in your build.gradle file?

Comment: yup, I have applied the plugin: "org.sonarqube  " in build.gradle